# Browser Incompatibility firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, video, cross-browser

I need help with this script that transform videos by css3 and js wrote by Christian Heilmann.
it works on safari and chrome but not in firefox...as anybody can tell me why?

this is the link to view an exemple page: http://sickmind.it/videotransform/transform_video.html

and this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mioii/c4Qtc/7/

the js code is this:

```
(function(){

/* predefine zoom and rotate */
  var zoom = 1,
      rotate = 0;

/* Grab the necessary DOM elements */
  var stage = document.getElementById('stage'),
      v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],
      controls = document.getElementById('controls');

/* Array of possible browser specific settings for transformation */
  var properties = ['transform', 'WebkitTransform', 'MozTransform',
                    'msTransform', 'OTransform'],
      prop = properties[0];

/* Iterators and stuff */    
  var i,j,t;

/* Find out which CSS transform the browser supports */
  for(i=0,j=properties.length;i<j;i++){
    if(typeof stage.style[properties[i]] !== 'undefined'){
      prop = properties[i];
      break;
    }
  }

/* Position video */
  v.style.left = 0;
  v.style.top = 0;

/* If there is a controls element, add the player buttons */
/* TODO: why does Opera not display the rotation buttons? */
  if(controls){
    controls.innerHTML =  '<button class="play">play</button>'+
                          '<div id="change">' +
                            '<button class="zoomin">+</button>' +
                            '<button class="zoomout">-</button>' +
                            '<button class="left">⇠</button>' +
                            '<button class="right">⇢</button>' +
                            '<button class="up">⇡</button>' +
                            '<button class="down">⇣</button>' +
                            '<button class="rotateleft">&#x21bb;</button>' +
                            '<button class="rotateright">&#x21ba;</button>' +
                            '<button class="reset">reset</button>' +
                          '</div>';
  }

/* If a button was clicked (uses event delegation)...*/
  controls.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    t = e.target;
    if(t.nodeName.toLowerCase()==='button'){

/* Check the class name of the button and act accordingly */    
      switch(t.className){

/* Toggle play functionality and button label */    
        case 'play':
          if(v.paused){
            v.play();
            t.innerHTML = 'pause';
          } else {
            v.pause();
            t.innerHTML = 'play';
          }
        break;

/* Increase zoom and set the transformation */
        case 'zoomin':
          zoom = zoom + 0.1;
          v.style[prop]='scale('+zoom+') rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
        break;

/* Decrease zoom and set the transformation */
        case 'zoomout':
          zoom = zoom - 0.1;
          v.style[prop]='scale('+zoom+') rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
        break;

/* Increase rotation and set the transformation */
        case 'rotateleft':
          rotate = rotate + 5;
          v.style[prop]='rotate('+rotate+'deg) scale('+zoom+')';
        break;
/* Decrease rotation and set the transformation */
        case 'rotateright':
          rotate = rotate - 5;
          v.style[prop]='rotate('+rotate+'deg) scale('+zoom+')';
        break;

/* Move video around by reading its left/top and altering it */
        case 'left':
          v.style.left = (parseInt(v.style.left,10) - 5) + 'px';
        break;
        case 'right':
          v.style.left = (parseInt(v.style.left,10) + 5) + 'px';
        break;
        case 'up':
          v.style.top = (parseInt(v.style.top,10) - 5) + 'px';
        break;
        case 'down':
          v.style.top = (parseInt(v.style.top,10) + 5) + 'px';
        break;

/* Reset all to default */
        case 'reset':
          zoom = 1;
          rotate = 0;
          v.style.top = 0 + 'px';
          v.style.left = 0 + 'px';
          v.style[prop]='rotate('+rotate+'deg) scale('+zoom+')';
        break;
      }        

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },false);
})();



/*
  Zooming and rotating HTML5 video player
  Homepage: http://github.com/codepo8/rotatezoomHTML5video
  Copyright (c) 2011 Christian Heilmann
  Code licensed under the BSD License:
  http://wait-till-i.com/license.txt
*/
```

isithackday.com/hacks/videozoomandrotate/transforming-video.html
i can't contact the author to ask info, hope somebody can help me! 
thanks guys!

Comment: Ok. The Safari and chrome use webkit engine to render and display the HTML while firefox uses Gecko. which causes differences. CSS3 properties supported by webkit are used and they unfortunately are/ may not be supported by firefox due to the same

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain video. Please add a http://path.mp4 or http://path.ogg to your video and update the fiddle

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal — The tutorial URL works fine in Firefox (and Christian Heilmann works for the Mozilla foundation!).

Comment: ehi guys! the fiddle is updated, and whit the Quentin's code and the .ogv file linked it works... on jsfiddle.net but on my page no, as anybody know why please?
http://sickmind.it/videotransform/transform_video.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation works fine on your example page. The video is not playing because you are providing it only in a format not supported by Firefox (at least on my platform). Provide an alternative in [a supported format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

From Christian's page (note the second `source` element):

```
<video>
  <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/P1120973_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">         
  <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/P1120973.ogv" type="video/ogg">         
    <p>Your browser doesn't support the HTML5 video tag it seems. 
       You can see this video as part of a collection 
       <a href="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/">
         at archive.org</a>.
    </p>         
</video>
```